# I keep getting this error when compiling main.cpp:3:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘do’ do ^ what do i do?

Tags: c++

Hello Im new to c++ and im working on a project 
 and i keep getting this error when im compiling

main.cpp:3:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘do’
 do
 ^

here's the code

```
int a,b,i,j,sum=0;

do
{   cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a < 4 || a > 1000000) 
    {   cout << "Input must be between 4 and 1000000 inclusive." << endl;
    }
}while (a < 4 || a > 1000000);

do
{   cout << "Enter a second number: ";
    cin >> b;
    if (b < 4 || b > 1000000) 
    {   cout << "Input must be between 4 and 1000000 inclusive." << endl;
    }
}while (b < 4 || b > 1000000);

if (a > b)
{   int hold;
    hold = b;
    b = a;
    a = hold;
}

cout << "The prime numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " inclusive are: " << endl;
//int sum;
for (i = a; i <= b; i++)
{
 for (j = 2; j <= i; j++) // Changed the < to <=, and got rid of semicolon
 {
    if (!(i%j)&&(i!=j)) break;
    if (j==i) 
    {
              cout << i << endl;
              sum += i;
              cout << sum ;

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your code needs to go in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Much like said before, your code does need to be in a function. Try wrapping it with

```
int main () {

//your code here

}
```